# Average interval between dates with random blanks

Tags: datetime, vba, excel, interval

I have a spreadsheet with order date data:

[image]

I need to find the average interval in days between each order date.  I have to both find a way to get past the blank cells in the row, and also take into account that some clients have 5-10 orders and some clients have 2 orders when calculating my average frequency (interval) between orders.

```
Sub DateInt()
    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    Dim CurrentRow As Integer
    Dim CurrentCol As Integer
    Dim GrandT As String
    Dim DateA As Date
    Dim DateB As Date
    Dim DateTtl As Integer
    Dim DateCount As Integer

    Set CurrentSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    LastRow = CurrentSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    LastCol = CurrentSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Cells(4, LastCol + 1).Value = "Avg Interval"
    Cells(4, LastCol + 2).Value = "Days Since Last Order"
    Cells(4, LastCol + 3).Value = "Last Order Date"
    Cells(4, LastCol + 4).Value = "Last Order v Avg Order"

    For CurrentRow = 5 To LastRow
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol).Value = Date
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
        DateCount = 0
        DateTtl = 0
        DateC = DateAdd("d", 20, Date)

        For CurrentCol = 2 To LastCol
            If Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol).Value = "" Then
            Else
                If DateCount < 1 Then
                    DateA = Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol).Value
                Else
                    DateB = Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol).Value
                    DateTtl = DateDiff("d", DateA, DateB) + DateTtl

                    If DateValue(DateB) = DateValue(Date) Then
                    Else
                        DateA = DateB
                    End If
                End If

                DateCount = DateCount + 1
            End If
        Next CurrentCol

        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 1).Value = DateTtl / DateCount
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 1).NumberFormat = "General"
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 2).Value = DateDiff("d", DateA, Date)
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 2).NumberFormat = "General"
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 3).Value = DateA
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 3).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 4).Value = Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 1).Value - Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 2).Value
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 4).NumberFormat = "#,##0_);[Red](#,##0)"
        Next CurrentRow

End Sub
```

**Here is what my code ended up doing:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing that stands right out is formatting cells in each iteration of a loop. Less to do within each iteration should speed things up just a bit so why not just format the entire column after the loop has done all the calculations?

I am not sure sure if you are working with more than one workbook or if that's part of an automated process but

```
Set CurrentSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
LastRow = CurrentSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
LastCol = CurrentSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

seems like a bit of an overkill. You are not using the `CurrentSheet` (pascal case vs camel case you know) anywhere in the code but you don't quality the `Cells`. Why not just:

```
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
lastCol = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Have you heard of offsets? Experience taught me that it's easier to maintain offsets rather than +1s +2s etc.

```
Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 1).Value = DateTtl / DateCount
```

=

```
Cells(currentRow, lastCol).Offset(0,1) = DateTtl / DateCount
```